# React json get value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I am new to react and started looking into pulling json data in.
To test I am using: https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5

What I am trying to achieve is when I click on a username from json, it will console log the username. How do I pass the value from json to console log?

```
const API = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      logins: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(API)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        let logins = data.results.map((uname) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <button>{uname.login.username}</button>
            </div>
          )
        })
        this.setState({logins: logins});
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.logins}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Is it a good idea to return html code in componentDidMount or should I leave it to render?

Comment: No, move out the html code from the `componentDidMount()`.

Comment: And as for first question: "How do I pass the value from json to console log?" - you can pass to console.log whole JSON or particular field using dot operator. console.log is very smart about printing whole JSON objects

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you like, but typically you'd leave component creation (it's not really HTML) to `render`:

```
const API = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      logins: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(API)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({logins: data.results});
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.logins.map((uname) => (
            <div>
              <button>{uname.login.username}</button>
            </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`state` should typically hold *data*, and leave the rendering of that data to `render`.

---

Side note: Your `fetch` call is missing two things:

1. A check for `ok` status, and
2. An error handler

   ```
   fetch(API)
     .then(response => {                             // ***
       if (!response.ok) {                           // ***
         throw new Error({status: response.status}); // ***
       }                                             // ***
     })                                              // ***
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(data => {
       // ...
     })
     .catch(err => {                                 // ***
       // Handle the error                           // ***
     });                                             // ***
   ```

`fetch` doesn't reject on status errors like 404.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do whatever you want, but for reading/usage purposes, it would be better to have all the `html` on the render. so changing your code should be like:

```
const API = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      logins: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(API)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        let logins = data.results.map((uname) => {
          return uname.login.username;
        })
        this.setState({logins: logins});
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      {
          this.state.logins.map(u=> {
              <div>
                  <button>{u}</button>
              </div>
          })
      }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```